# Inequality with determinants problem

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

Let $A,B \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ with $AB=BA.$ Prove that: $$\det(A^{2}+AB+B^{2})\geq (\det(A)-\det(B))^{2}$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to start, to be honest. I tried multiplication of both sides with det(A)+det(b) but we don't know if this is positive or negative, so it's no solution. I hope someone will provide some identity for determinants i don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inequality is false. Take

$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \
B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then $A^2=B^2=A,AB=B$ so

$$
A^2+AB+B^2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So

$$
{\sf det}(A^2+AB+B^2)=3, \
({\sf det}(A)-{\sf det}(B))^2=4
$$